# Motion & Fitness on iPhone 5/5C

Tags: iphone, core-motion

From what I know iPhone 5/5C do not have the motion processor like 5S and newer phones have, but when I request the motion permission the default alert with Allow and Don't allow still appears, even if I check before if the motion is available for device with `MotionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable`. I would expect the alert not to appear for 5 and 5C.

What am I doing wrong here? Does 5 and 5C actually support motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @the4kman said the device motion is available through accelerometer and a gyroscope.

But what I actually meant and needed in this case is the user's activity, which is available through the M7 processor that is installed on 5S and newer and to check if that is available on a device I did `CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable()`

Answer (score 1):

No, you are getting this wrong; `isDeviceMotionAvailable` detects the presence of a **gyroscope** and an **accelerometer**. It's actually available since iOS 4, which came out *way before* the M7 motion coprocessor inside the iPhone 5s.

[From Apple Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616094-isdevicemotionavailable)

> The device-motion service is available **if a device has both an accelerometer and a gyroscope**.

Comment: You're right. I got this wrong. Actually I think I asked it wrong. What I need is actually the motion activity and I believe that is available only on M7 and later. Right?

Comment: And I believe I should check for that with CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable(). I'll delete the question or maybe add an answer in case someone else stumbles over this as well